# Capturing web data sent and received by a desktop application

Tags: windows

I have an MP3-tagging application that auto fetches lyrics from some unknown source. How do I figure out what kind of request it is sending, and to which source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a sniffer. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), for example. Will show you all the network communication that gets out of your computer and comes back, should be fairly easy to figure out the rest.

Comment: Okay, so I had tried Wireshark before posting this question. I'm not very sure if I was doing it right, but all I saw was a lot of IPs and binary data. Is there something like the Firefox developer console that would let me look at the requests and the responses?

Comment: You can [watch a TCP stream](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html) in Wireshark. It will format the communication to user-readable messages. Note, however, that this will only work if this is a TCP-based communication. Also, if the transferred content is mostly binary, this is what you'll see (if it's encrypted, no network tool will show you the actual content). But most chances are watching the TCP stream will give you what you want.

Comment: I doubt it's encrypted. I'll check the 'Follow TCP stream' feature and report back. Thanks!